# what went wrong with my logistic regression implementation in c++?

Tags: c++, r, armadillo, logistic-regression

I have implemented a simple logistic regression function with IRLS algorithm using the armadillo linear algebra libray:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/math/distributions/normal.hpp>
#include <boost/math/distributions/students_t.hpp>
#include <armadillo>
#include <cmath>

using namespace boost::math;
arma::mat getW(
    arma::mat& beta,
    arma::mat& X,
    std::string family,
    std::string link
)
{
    arma::mat w;
    if(family == "poisson") {
        if(link == "identity") {
            w = arma::diagmat(1/(X * beta));
        }
    }
    else if(family == "binomial") {
        if(link == "logit") {
            arma::colvec tmp = exp(X * beta);
            w = arma::diagmat(tmp/pow(1+tmp, 2));
        }
    }
    else {
        throw 1;
    }
    return w;
}

arma::mat getz(
    arma::mat& y,
    arma::mat& beta,
    arma::mat& X,
    std::string family,
    std::string link
)
{
    arma::mat z;
    if(family == "poisson") {
        if(link == "identity") {
            z = y;
        }
    }
    else if(family == "binomial") {
        if(link=="logit") {
            arma::mat tmp = exp(X * beta);
            z = X*beta + y % (pow(1+tmp, 2)/tmp) - 1 - tmp;
        }
    }
    else {
        throw 1;
    }
    return z;
}

inline arma::mat glmMat(
    arma::mat& y,
    arma::mat& x,
    std::string family,
    std::string link
)
{

    int n = x.n_rows;
    int k = x.n_cols;

    // add a col of all ones
    arma::mat allOne(n, 1, arma::fill::ones);
    x.insert_cols(0, allOne);
    ++k;

    arma::mat res(k, 4);

    if(family=="binomial" and link=="logit")
    {
        arma::mat coef(k, 1, arma::fill::zeros);
        arma::mat W = getW(coef, x, family, link);
        arma::mat z = getz(y, coef, x, family, link);

        try {
            arma::mat J = x.t() * W * x;
            arma::colvec coef1 = arma::solve(J, x.t()*W*z);
            double coefdiff = max(abs(coef - coef1));
            while(coefdiff >= 0.00001) {
                coef = coef1;
                W = getW(coef, x, family, link);
                z = getz(y, coef, x, family, link);
                J = x.t() * W * x;
                coef1 = arma::solve(J, x.t()*W*z);
                coefdiff = max(abs(coef - coef1));
            }


            arma::mat coefVarMatrix = J.i();
            arma::colvec coefVar = coefVarMatrix.diag();
            arma::colvec coefSe = pow(coefVar, .5);
            arma::colvec zscore = coef / coefSe;
            res.col(0) = coef;
            res.col(1) = coefSe;
            res.col(2) = zscore;

            // calculate p values
            auto d = normal_distribution<>();
            for(int i=0; i<k; i++) {
                double p = 2 * (1 - cdf(d, fabs(res(i, 2))));
                if(p < 0 or p > 1) {
                    std::cerr << "Pval is abnormal from glm, dumping data to /tmp/tmpx.csv and /tmp/tmpy.csv" << std::endl;
                    x.save("/tmp/tmpx.csv", arma::csv_ascii);
                    y.save("/tmp/tmpy.csv", arma::csv_ascii);
                    throw 1;
                }
                res(i, 3) = p;
            }
        }
        catch(...) {
            std::cout << "something wrong..." << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        throw 1;
    }
    return res;
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    {
        int nr = 5000;
        int ncx = 50;
        arma::mat x(nr, ncx, arma::fill::randu);
        arma::mat y = arma::randi<arma::mat>(nr, 1, arma::distr_param(0, 1));
        arma::mat xcol;
        arma::mat res(ncx, 4);
        for(int i=0; i<ncx; i++) {
            xcol = x(arma::span::all, i);
            res.row(i) = (glmMat(y, xcol, "binomial", "logit")).row(1);
        }
        res.print("res..........");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled it like this:

```
g++ glm.cpp --std=c++11 -larmadillo -llapack -lblas -o bin
```

The main function simulates a 5000x50 data set and performs logistic regression on each of them, the whole process takes about 23 seconds on my laptop.

Doing largely the same thing in R, it takes about 2 seconds:

```
testglm = function() {
        x = matrix(rnorm(5000*50), 5000)
        y = matrix(sample(0:1, 5000, repl=T), 5000)
        res = apply(x, 2, function(coli) summary(glm(y~coli, family=binomial))$coef[2, ])
        # print(res)
        }

system.time(testglm())
   user  system elapsed 
  2.049   0.000   2.049
```

I am wondering what went wrong with my implementation?

Comment: Try with `-O3`. I don't know about R but it might use multithreading so you should do it on your C++ code and try vectorzation.

Comment: -O3 does not help at all.